# CommandLink doesn't work. Tried everything

Tags: jsf

it's my first question on the site :) But first, sorry for my bad english, i'm learning :)
Plz, i need your help. I'm blocked with an application in JSF.

I have this

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./defaultTemplate.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">

                    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0px">#{msg.default_2}</h1>
                    <br/>
                    <ul style="padding-left: 0px">

                        <ui:repeat value="#{categoryMB.categories}" var="categorie">              
                                <h:outputLabel value=" -==- " style="color: #FF8620; font-size: 10px; padding-left: 0px"></h:outputLabel>
                                <h:form>
                                <h:commandLink value="#{categorie.categoryname}" action="#{categoryMB.getItemsByCat(categorie.categoryid.id)}"/> 
                                </h:form>
                        </ui:repeat>

                    </ul>


                    <ui:repeat value="#{categoryMB.listItems}" var="item">
                        <div class="itemCategory">
                            <h:graphicImage class="item-image" url="#{item.urlimage}"/> 
                            <h:outputLabel value="#{item.price} €" class="prix"></h:outputLabel>
                            <br/>
                            <h2><h:outputLabel value="#{item.name}"></h:outputLabel></h2>
                            <br/>
                            <h:form>

                                <h:commandLink value="#{msg.default_14}" action="#{itemMB.linkItem(item.id)}"
></h:commandLink>

                            </h:form>
                        </div>
                    </ui:repeat>

            </ui:define>


        </ui:composition>

    </body> </html>
```

Everything is good, except the second **commandLink** !
I can't execute the action. I always return on the same page...
I tried everything i could and i read all subjects about that on the site but i can't find a solution. Please, i'm asking you, help me. I'm going to be crazy.

**My bean for categoryMB :**

```
package managedBean;

import entityBean.Item;
import entityBean.Translatecategory;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import sessionBean.ItemFacadeLocal;
import sessionBean.TranslatecategoryFacadeLocal;

/**
 *
 * @author Aurélien
 */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CategoryMB {
    @EJB
    private ItemFacadeLocal itemFacade;
    @EJB
    private TranslatecategoryFacadeLocal translatecategoryFacade;


    @ManagedProperty("#{internationalizationMB}")
    private InternationalizationMB language;

    private List<Item> listItems;
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CategoryMB
     */
    public CategoryMB() {
    }

    public List<Translatecategory> getCategories () {     
        return translatecategoryFacade.findByLanguage(language.getLocale().getLanguage());       
    }

    public void getItemsByCat (int idCat) {
        setListItems(itemFacade.findByCat(idCat));
    }


    public InternationalizationMB getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(InternationalizationMB language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public List<Item> getListItems() {
        return listItems;
    }

    public void setListItems(List<Item> listItems) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }
}
```

And my bean for itemMB :

```
package managedBean;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ItemMB implements Serializable {

    private int idItem;
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ItemMB
     */
    public ItemMB() {
    }

    public int getIdItem() {
        return idItem;
    }

    public void setIdItem(int idItem) {
        this.idItem = idItem;
    }

    public String linkItem(int id)
    {
        setIdItem(id);
        return "item";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing CDI `@SessionScoped` with JSF 2.x `@SessionScoped`. This is noted in your imports:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ItemMB implements Serializable {
    //...
}
```

This makes your managed bean to have the default scope, which in JSF 2 is `@RequestScoped`, so your managed bean will be re created on every request.

Fix your import to:

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
```

---

If you happen to use JSF 2.2.x, start working everything with CDI 1.1. Use `@Named` for your managed beans and use `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` for `@ViewScoped`.

More info:

- [What's new in JSF 2.2. CDI compatible @ViewScoped](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087)